# Jenkins agent machines stops abruptly

Tags: java, jenkins

On jenkins 2.107.3, I have created 1 agent with 1 executor. When I run jobs it them, Sometimes jenkins agent is able to run full build but most of the times it dies with "Resource temporarily unavailable". Even, If I add different hosts as agent, the outcome was the same.

Resource temporarily unavailable seems to be like an SSH error. However, normal ssh connections works fine. Can someone shed light on why jenkins is acting in this manner?

Error:

> hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$Unexporter run
>
> WARNING: Couldn't clean up oid=8 from null
>
> java.io.IOException: Resource temporarily unavailable
>
> ```
>  at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
>  at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
>  at hudson.remoting.StandardOutputStream.write(StandardoutputStream.java:88)
>  at hudson.remoting.ChunkedOutputStream.sendFrame(ChunkedOutputStream.java:90)
>  at hudson.remoting.ChunkedOutputStream.sendBreak(ChunkedOutputStream.java:62)
>  at hudson.remoting.ChunkedCommandTransport.writeBlock(ChunkedCommandTransport.java:46)
>  at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandtransport.write(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandtransport.java:50)
>  at hudson.remoting.Channel.send(Channel.java:719)
>
>  ..............
> ```
>
> Error: Connection terminated
>
> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 1B8BACED
>
> ```
>  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:866)
>  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
>  at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48)
>  .......
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It is a really old remoting issue [JENKINS-49472](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49472) resolved on latest Jenkins versions (>2.112)

Comment: Thanks. Include the Jenkins version number for which it was fixed. I would up-vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if some event capture in /var/log/messages  or /var/log/secure

It seems your machine is occipied in other operation and kernal unable to free resource for your process.

Thanks,
MM